# Reasons why a publication may go by a nickname or partial name rather than published name?

Tags: business, conceptualization

For instance, if a publication is published as "NLB Membership Buyer & Resource Guide" and instead it is being promoted as "NLB Membership Guide" should there be a reason in the publication why it is being called "NLB Membership Guide," rather than the full name? Or should the publication be renamed to "NLB Membership Guide"? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That's not really a question for graphic design but workplace dynamics.

Perhaps people were desperate to make sure nobody wouldn't get it and slapped everything on the front they could. Microsoft designers [did a joke at how they always do that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUXnJraKM3k) many years ago.

Or could be because someone in the Resource department got really cross that their department was unrepresented on the cover and stamped and shouted until they got their way. Whereupon everyone ignored the big long title and only used the meaningful bit of it.